# Looking for loading more scene when node goes above Y

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am looking for a way to make my game load more SKScene when my node (ball) goes above certain Y position.

I'm looking for a way to make the loading a little bit like ColorSwitch game where you tap and the ball loads more screen once you hit a certain Y position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SKCameraNode` and have it centered on your scene (or wherever it is you want to look at). Check documentation or search here for more help on setting up your camera.

In `update()` simply check the position of ball's y value `ball!.position.y`, if it's past a threshold such as `view!.bounds.y`, move your camera up by however much `camera!.runAction(SKAction.moveBy...)`

If you want to scroll back down, it would be a bit more complicated, but the same principles would apply.

(note: I have my stuff as Optionals so your code may not have `!`)
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcameranode

You could also use invisible boxes and collision detection, but that seems more complicated of an approach to me >.>

If you post some code we can help you get it up and running. Unfortunately, there will be some degree of math involved x[